# How to apply the same functions (which use the files' names) on more datasets in R

Tags: r, function, dataset

I am new in R *(if you know some good online courses in R, I'll be glad for any recommendation")* and I am trying to apply the same set of functions for statistical analysis to many datasets (here is an example of part of my dataset.)

[image: an example of part of my dataset]

This is how I do it individually

```
ims.no3.1.csv <- read.csv("M:\\blabla\\datasetname1.csv", sep=",")
ims.no3.non0.1 <- filter_if(ims.no3.1.csv, is.numeric, all_vars((.) != 0))
ims.no3.1 <- data.frame(value = rep(ims.no3.non0.1$bin.start, ims.no3.non0.1$count))
basicStats(ims.no3.1)
h.ims.no3.1 <- hist(ims.no3.1$value, breaks = 400, ylim = c(0,400),xlim=c(0,3), xlab = "lifetime (ns)", main = "Histogram of ims+no3_1")
```

So I was trying to make my own function and then apply it with "lapply" but I don't know how to deal  with the names that I have to use (at least for the "rep" and "filter_if" functions)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to perform the same analysis on multiple datasets.  A simple example is below, where I find the dimensions of a group of datasets in my working directory:

```
setwd("YourPath:/")
all<-list.files(pattern = ".csv") # using a list of my csv files

# analyze each file in list
# e.g. What are the dimensions of these files?
a<-list()
for (i in 1:length(all)){  # for each of the csv files in the list..
  message("i=", all[i])
    a[[i+1]]<-dim(read.csv(all[i]))   # compute the dimensions and write to list
  print(a)  # print the result
  }
```

This loop above will print the dimensions (rows and columns) of the datasets in my working directory.  You can adapt to compute means, sums, plot or write RMD files, etc..

Comment: Thank You @Ben, using this loop I managed to remove the zeroes from my datasets, but now I need to repeat the bin values by their counts (e.g. if bin 0.715 has 11 counts, than I want the value to be 11times in the column). I tryed this, but it gives me a data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows: `repcount <- list()
for (i in 1:length(all)){  
  message("i=", all[i])
  repcount[[i]] <-data.frame(value= rep(non0[i]$bin.start, non0[i]$count))
  print(repcount[i])
}`